# narrow conversion compile warning. How to fix it?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-warnings

I'm getting the below compile time warning:

```
warning C4838: conversion from 'int' to 'TCHAR' requires a narrowing conversion
```

The warning is based on the following code:

```
TCHAR driveName[] = { TEXT('A') + i, TEXT(':'), TEXT('\\'), TEXT('\0') };
```

Comment: The `+ i` seems to be causing the `int` promotion of the first element of the list. You will have to `static_cast` it to `TCHAR` to avoid the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addition `TEXT('A') + i` will do the usual integer promotions, converting both operands to integer and producing an integer result. You must explicitly cast the result back to `TCHAR` to tell the compiler your intentions and eliminate the warning.

```
TCHAR driveName[] = { static_cast<TCHAR>(TEXT('A') + i), TEXT(':'), TEXT('\'), TEXT('\0') };
```

Answer (score 1):

`TEXT('A') + i` involves integer promotion, so the warning. To silent the warning, you may cast result to `TCHAR`.

BTW, There are no guaranty that letters `'A'`-`'Z'` are contiguous in C++ (see [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) for counter example).

Something along `TEXT("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")[i]` should fix the warning, and be portable.